# How to move up or down a slot from a material/vgroup/dupliob list?

Tags: python, scripting

i'm wondering how to use thoses operator in a slot list within a python script.

[image]

in a Count list inside of a particle system, order is really important. i absolutely need to be able to move them freely up or down until X index. and the only way i found is with the context operator below. which can only be used when the editor is set to properties -> particles -> with the use coult tab open. And this is not handy at all.

this is the operator:

```
bpy.ops.particle.dupliob_move_up()
bpy.ops.particle.dupliob_move_down()
```

i think peoples who like to move material and vgroup slot will have the same issue.

This is the only solution i found. which is quite bad.

```
old_editor = bpy.context.area.ui_type


#bpy.ops.particle.dupliob_move_up()
#bpy.ops.particle.dupliob_move_down()

bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'PROPERTIES'
bpy.context.space_data.context = 'PARTICLES'

#bpy.ops.particle.dupliob_move_up()
bpy.ops.particle.dupliob_move_down()

bpy.context.area.ui_type = old_editor
```

and i didn't even find a way to open this list, so this code will not work if the list is closed

as for rewriting a value. there's not a lot of choice here ?

[image]

Comment: You don't have to use the operator, you can change the index for each material in the collection: `C.object.material_slots[0].material = bpy.data.materials['Material.002']`. To get the current index there is `C.object.active_material_index` and you can get the the size of the collection via `len(MaterialSlots)`. There should be equivalent properties for the particle collection.

Comment: couldn't find it in the console ? i'm searching in the api, there's none either https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.ParticleDupliWeight.html#bpy.types.ParticleDupliWeight

Comment: Here you go: `Object.particle_systems.active_index` and `Object.particle_systems.active`

Comment: thanks @brockmann. but what about the other operators ? like removing for examples

Comment: Wasn't part of the question... for material slots there is `pop()` and `clear()`:
`C.object.data.materials.pop(index=1, update_data=True)` and there is probably the same for particle systems...

Comment: woohoo thanks !

Comment: Did you find something for the particles? @DB3D

Comment: i did find pop but unfortunately the arguments are not valid at all.